# Need to place a Bomb in cocos2d game continuously by pressing bomb button

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Right now am placing the bomb after removing the first one ,now thw requirement is to place the bombs continuously and that bomb has only one sprite sheet,there am getting problem like if first bomb is placed and immediatly second bomb is placed than first bomb is not removing.
Plz help me and am new to cocos2d

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
   @"Bombs.plist"];
   _spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Bombs.png"];
   [_tileMap addChild:_spriteSheet z:100 ];NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = 
    [NSMutableArray       array];
    for(int i = 1; i <=20; ++i)
    {
    [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] 
    spriteFrameByName:     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bomb_%d.png", i]]]; 
    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation   animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
    _bomb= [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bomb_1.png" ];
     _bomb.position =_player.position;
    [_bomb runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2f],
   [CCAnimate   actionWithAnimation:walkAnim],[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:
   self    selector:@selector(spriteDone:)],nil]];
    [_spriteSheet addChild:_bomb z:100];


// selector to remove bomb

- (void)spriteDone:(id)sender { 
    [_spriteSheet removeChild:_bomb cleanup:YES];
     _bombRemoved =TRUE; NSLog(@"Bool value: %d",_bombRemoved); 
}
```

Comment: Show your current code.

Comment: the devil is in the details : show some (code)

Comment: if(_player._bigBomb==TRUE) {[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"BigBomb.plist"]; _spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"BigBomb.png"];
 [_tileMap addChild:_spriteSheet z:100 ]; NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];for(int i = 1; i <=20; ++i)
{[walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BigBomb_%d.png", i]]];}CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
 _bomb= [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Bomb_1.png" ];

Comment: After That am removing in spritr done method                                         _bomb.position =_player.position;[_bomb runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2f],[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim],[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteDone:)],nil]];[_spriteSheet addChild:_bomb z:100];

Comment: When placing code rather edit question than place it in comment in code section, otherwise it's hard to read.

Comment: Thing is , this code snippet is not relevant to your question : i dont see any code related to the logic for placement and deletion of this animation.

Comment: am using the above code in cctouchbegan for tap=1 and am removing in spritedone method

Comment: errr ... what about 'show the code' ?

Comment: - (void)spriteDone:(id)sender
{
   [_spriteSheet removeChild:_bomb cleanup:YES];
     _bombRemoved =TRUE;
   NSLog(@"Bool value: %d",_bombRemoved); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2 : make certain bomb disappears after the animation completes AND upon next touch.

```
// where you determine the touch should add a bomb
if(_bomb) {
  [_bomb removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
  _bomb = nil;
}

// do your stuff creating new _bomb object

// when you create the action, change to :

[_bomb runAction:[CCSequence actions:
   [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2f],
   [CCAnimate   actionWithAnimation:walkAnim],
   [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ 
          [_bomb removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
          _bombRemoved = YES;
          _bomb=nil;
      }
   ],nil]
];
```

Comment: ya but now my requirement is to place that bomb continuously for every tap=1 and remove after explosion.

Comment: right now if am placing the second bomb continuously the  first bomb is not removing

Comment: So what will be the solution for placing continuously bombs ?

Comment: YvesLeBorg i think ur not understanding my problem

Comment: YvesLeBorg i think ur not understanding my problem . Right now am able to remove the bomb after explosion.The thing is am using the same sprite sheet for second bomb also so am not able to remove the first bomb after placing second bomb and it is not cleaning first bomb. so my question is is there any way to place the bombs using one sprite sheet continuously? and am new to cocos2d .......!

Comment: ure right, my answer was wrong, i misread your code. updating my answer.

Comment: YvesLeBorg i have one more doubt like i want to do first bomb work as it is when second bomb placed and after complition of its work it should clean up and same for the second bomb after placing third bomb....